# Guidance on Powershell command or script to sort directories evenly based on amount of data

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line, grep, command-line-arguments

I am in the process of moving my file server from on-prem up to an Azure file share/VM.

I've got everything in place and ready to move, but I am wanting to divide my files up and do it in 4 roughly equal sized batches.

**The Question **

If I had 100 directories on my fileserver full of data, named Dir1 - Dir100.

What command would help me figure out something like below:

Dir_1 – Dir_30 == 25% of total amount of data

Dir_31 -- Dir_65 == 25% of total amount of data

Dir_66 – Dir_90 == 25% of total amount of data

Dir_91 – Dir_100 == 25% of total amount of data

Does this make sense?

I know how to get total data size or number of files.... But I cannot figure out if what I am trying to do is possible or how to do it. I have been messing around, but I'm not even getting close.

Comment: Do they need to be in contiguous blocks (i.e., Dir01 to Dir30 all together), or do they need to be in the most even combination even if they're in an arbitrary order (i.e., group 1 is Dir01, Dir05, Dir33, Dir76, etc.)?

Comment: Contiguous blocks.

Comment: you can either work thru the list assigning items to each batch until you get to the max size for a batch OR use array slicing to grab items in chunks. the 2nd is likely easier. array slice = `$Collection[$FirstIndex..$LastIndex]`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I did it both ways. You didn't post anything of your own, so you'll have to adapt what I have here.

First, create a list of your directories. The two Partition fields here are just going to be which group they belong to. You'll want the sequential partition based on your comment.

```
# Set the number of partitions you need to divide into
$PartitonCount = 4

# I'm making my own list.
# DirectoryName is the FullName of the directory, while Size is the total size of the folder
$Directories = @'
DirectoryName,Size,SequentialPartition,BalancedPartition
Dir001,667117278790,,
Dir002,292429698039,,
Dir003,886665781748,,
Dir004,49665832174,,
Dir005,34041573768,,
Dir006,320236552339,,
Dir007,747674470078,,
Dir008,375284137393,,
Dir009,549754879999,,
Dir010,327528841615,,
Dir011,1079085662940,,
Dir012,1051279115201,,
Dir013,198772106622,,
Dir014,124437323951,,
Dir015,342261556929,,
Dir016,844330660560,,
Dir017,888294129196,,
Dir018,774656795794,,
Dir019,360019686543,,
Dir020,412884330229,,
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Now, for the sequential partitioning:

```
# Determine the total size of all directories
$TotalSize = $Directories | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum

# This is the threshold for sequential balancing
$PartitionSizeThreshold = $TotalSize / $PartitonCount

# Initialize the partition size and partition ID
[int64]$CurrentPartitionSize = 0
$CurrentPartition = 0
foreach ($D in $Directories) {
    # Assign the file to the current partition
    $D.SequentialPartition = $CurrentPartition

    # Add the current file's size to the current partition's size
    $CurrentPartitionSize += $D.Size

    # If the current partition's size is over the threshold, go to the next empty partition
    if ($CurrentPartitionSize -gt $PartitionSizeThreshold) {
        $CurrentPartition++
        $CurrentPartitionSize = 0
    }
}

# Results
$Directories
```

You can see how well balanced it is with this:

```
# Here is the breakdown of the sequential partitions as a fraction of the total
$Directories |
    Group-Object -Property SequentialPartition |
    ForEach-Object {
         ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) / $TotalSize 
    }
```

The last partition is likely to be pretty poorly balanced.

---

On the other hand, if it needs to be as balanced as possible:

```
# Create the partiton size array with a zero for each partition size
$BalancedPartitionSizes = 1..$PartitonCount | ForEach-Object { 0 }

# Sort largest to smallest to assign the largest directories first
$Directories | Sort-Object -Property Size -Descending |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Determine which index of the array has is the smallest size
        $SmallestPartition = $BalancedPartitionSizes | Sort-Object | Select-Object -First 1 | ForEach-Object { [Array]::IndexOf($BalancedPartitionSizes, $_) }

        # Add the directory to the smallest partition
        $BalancedPartitionSizes[$SmallestPartition] += $_.Size
        $_.BalancedPartition = $SmallestPartition
    }

# Results
$Directories | Sort-Object -Property BalancedPartition
```

And you can see how efficiently it balanced things:

```
# Here is the breakdown of the balanced partitions as a fraction of the total
$Directories |
    Group-Object -Property BalancedPartition |
    ForEach-Object {
        ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) / $TotalSize 
    }
```

This is much more likely to give you a more equal balancing, though it's certainly not perfect.

Comment: Thank you for this. My project got put on hold for a couple weeks. But I'm looping back to this before I start it up again.